# Probability problem - Binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I was trying to solve the following problem:

"100 students registered for an exam. The professor knows that each of them will actually take the exam, independently from all the others, with probability 60%. How many tests does he have to print out so that the probability of having enough tests is 98%?"

I was thinking that calculating the probability of printing out enough tests for the exam, let's say $k$, is equivalent to calculate the probability that $k$ students will actually take the exam. So I thought this process can be modelled with a binomial variable, where each $X_i$ represents a student.

Then 
$$98=\mathbb P(X> k)=1- \mathbb P(X\le k)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0.02=\mathbb P(X\le k)=\binom{100}{k}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{100-k}=\binom{100}{k}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{100}.$$

Is this "one" correct way to proceed? If so, How can I solve this equation with respect to $k$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would be fine once you fix some things, but perhaps a more convenient to calculate approach would be using normal distributions.  $n=100,p=0.6,q=0.4$, the average number of students arriving will be $np=60$ and the standard deviation will be $\sqrt{npq}=\sqrt{24}\approx 4.899$.  How many standard deviations above the mean (*what z-score*) will result in $98\%$ of the data lying to the left?  How many tests does this method suggest then that you need?  Now that you have a good estimate, you can check against the actual distribution itself, does it work as you hoped?

Comment: Also, note: $\binom{100}{k}(\frac{2}{5})^k(\frac{3}{5})^{100-k}$ is the probability $Pr(X\color{red}{=}k)$, not $Pr(X\color{red}{\leq}k)$, you'll have to add up terms to account for that, making the method described in my first comment that much more convenient.

Comment: So, are you using a Poisson variable? If so, I read it is supposed to be the limit of a Binomial distribution whith parameter $\lambda=np$. But $n$ is to be sufficiently big. Is this the case in your opinion? Moreover why is the standard deviation equal to $\sqrt{npq}$?

Comment: Not a poisson distribution, a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).  The *normal* distribution is the limit of a binomial distribution, not the poisson distribution.  As for why the mean and standard deviation are what they are, these are well known properties of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  As to the question of whether or not it is sufficiently large... its "large enough" that it gives us at least a ballpark estimate, but small enough that we should check more closely if able.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that a binomial variable could be approximated by a normal one for $n$ sufficiently large. Now I get what you meant. But one last question. What do you mean when you say "check again the actual distribution"? Am I supposed to use the estimate of $k$ in the formula I wrote above?

Comment: What I meant by check the distribution is the same as I was getting at in the comment on the question below.  $P(X\color{red}{= k}) = \binom{100}{k}0.4^k0.6^{100-k}$.  On the other hand $P(X\color{red}{\geq k}) = \color{red}{\sum\limits_{n=k}^{100}}\binom{100}{n}0.4^n0.6^{100-n}$ and $P(X\color{red}{\leq k})=\color{red}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^k}\binom{100}{n}0.4^n0.6^{100-n}$.  You said "there isn't a summation used in binomial distributions" which is totally incorrect when referring to finding probability of $X$ lying within *a range of values*.

Comment: That's ok. Of course there is a sum in this case since you are not valuing a probability on a single value. Sorry for that, I was getting confused. Thanks a lot, you were very clear and patient!